# WPF Splash Screen Adding Fails

Tags: wpf, splash-screen

I need to put up a png image as splash screen for my WPF.

I imported the file to project and changed Build Action to 'Splash Screen'

This should have done the job, but I am getting this error message:

```
Unknown build error, 'An item with the same key has already been added.'
```

Googling the error didn't help.

Comment: Remove that png image then rename it. After that add it to the project and set the build action to `SplashScreen` and see if the problem was solved.

Comment: No, this did not solve the problem. However, something else did. I changed the Build Action arbitrarily to Application Definition and then build, of course with errors, then switched back to SplashScreen. I don't understand how or why, but it did work.

Comment: I suppose you removed the image and it worked, right?

Answer (score 11):

I can confirm that changing the build action to Application Definition and then building (there will be errors), then switching it back to Splash Screen and running the program clears this error.

Comment: Solution still valid in VS 2019 preview!

Comment: Well, that's surprising.